# Relocation expenses - Contract job

Tags: job-offer, job-change, contracts, contractors, canada

In Canada, I have been offered a new contract job, located in different province.

Quebec to Ontario

To start my new job, I need to relocate from current province.

---

As the new job offer is contract based(hourly),

Does it make sense to ask for relocation expenses from client? Any document reference wrt Canadian law..

Comment: Even though they may not offer relocation expenses, the government will provide you assistance for this move (equivalent to your Marginal Tax Rate times the claim-able amount) through a credit on your next tax return on line 219: (https://www.canada.ca/en/revenue-agency/services/tax/individuals/topics/about-your-tax-return/tax-return/completing-a-tax-return/deductions-credits-expenses/line-219-moving-expenses.html)

Answer (score 4):

> As the new job offer is contract based(hourly),
>
> Does it make sense to ask for relocation expenses from client?

You can ask for anything. (If you work for a contracting agency, you might want to run this question by them first).

Unless the job requires specific expertise that very few possess, it seems unlikely that the company would offer relocation expenses for a contractor.

I hired many contractors. I never paid relocation expenses.

Comment: Doesn't Canada law have any guidelines on this?

Comment: They are yet to generate offer letter. I have already ask them and they replied that permanent jobs are given relocation explenses

Comment: @overexchange i agree with Joe's answer, but to add flavour - when i contracted i was, on multiple times, offered relocation expenses. These included airfares, 3 months accomodation.

Comment: @bharal Did you ask for relocation expenses?